# How would this Objective-C code be written in Swift 3?

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I have this piece of Objective-C code and I'm breaking my had as to how to write this in Swift instead:

```
NSData *data = [NSData data];
char vals[value.length];
[value getBytes:vals length:value.length];
Point3D aPoint;

aPoint.x = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[0] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[1] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;
aPoint.y = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[2] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[3] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;
aPoint.z = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[4] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[5] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;
```

I've tried using this:

```
    let data: NSData = NSData(data: characteristic.value!)
    var vals = [CChar16](repeating: CChar16(), count: data.length)
```

but that only resulted in:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [CChar16]' (aka 'inout
>   Array')

any help would be greatly appreciated.